# Passing arguments to dap-mode (c++)

Tags: debugging, c++

everyone. I am new to debugging with [dap-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode) and i can't figure out
how to pass arguments.

I tried by creating a template

```el
(dap-register-debug-template
  "GDB::Mine"
  (list :type "gdb"
        :request "launch"
        :args "/home/george/Documents/Repos/pop/encoder/OBJs/Buddha.obj"
        :name "GDB::Mine"
        :target nil
        :program "/home/george/Documents/Repos/pop/encoder/build/addon"
        :cwd "/home/george/Documents/Repos/pop/encoder/"))
```

but it doesn't work. It gives me

```
No source file named /home/george/Documents/Repos/olive/app/main.cpp.
Program exited with code 0377
undefinedPlease give path to .obj file.
```

I actually don't know why it tells that there isn't an olive/app/main.cpp file since that's not the project i'm trying to debug.

What am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are specified with `:arguments` instead of `:args` like the VSCode configuration.

Reference: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/247

Comment: Doesnt seem to work with the cpptools plugin. (dap-register-debug-template
  "cpptools::Run Configuration"
  (list :type "cppdbg"
        :request "launch"
        :name "cpptools::Run Configuration"
        :MIMode "gdb"
        :arguments "128"
        :program "${workspaceFolder}/inttobin"
        :cwd "${workspaceFolder}"))

Comment: @RichieHH Agreed,. Did you find a solution?